# Looping an input

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to type in a sentence, than it asks them to repeat it however times they desire, but I am having trouble. This is what I have so far, but I don't know what to do next or add to it. I just need help trying to repeat the sentence that outputs according to the amount that's inputted.

```
def main():
    sentence= input("Enter a sentence: ")
    x= input("Specify how many times to print it: ")
    for x in range():
            print(sentence)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a tutorial service

Comment: voting as an off-topic too

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop x times, not change x as a loop counter.

```
for n in range(int(x)):
        print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def main():
    sentence= input("Enter a sentence: ")
    x = ""
    while not x.isdigit():
        input("Specify how many times to print it: ")
    for _ in range(int(x)):
        print(sentence)
```

Yours doesn't work for two reasons: `input()` returns a string, not an integer; and [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) requires at least one argument.